# RFT get .text value from Html.SELECT and compare with a reg exp

Tags: rft

I need to identify the Html.SELECT object from my application and select it.
I am succesfull in doing that, but now I cannot write the entire .text string in my code as its a long list of all locations.
How can I pull that value and compare it with a regular expression.
For example - .text is District................................................

and I want to have a string variable as District.*
In the below code I need the string name as a regular expression

```
SelectMCASDistrict("District.*");

public static void SelectMCASDistrict(String name)
{
   GuiTestObject textObj = findTextObjectDist(name);
   if (textObj != null) {

    ((SelectGuiSubitemTestObject) textObj).select("Abington.*");
     } else {
       throw new ObjectNotFoundException();
   }
} 


private static GuiTestObject findTextObjectDist(String name)
{

    TestObject[] tobs = find(atDescendant(".class", "Html.SELECT", ".text", name ), true);

    if(tobs.length == 0)
        return null;
    return (GuiTestObject)tobs[0];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is possible. Instead of giving to `find` method search conditions in `String` format, you can use the `Property` class, as stated [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/rfttreasures/entry/pattern_based_property_matching16?lang=en).

This way, your code will became:

```
private static GuiTestObject findTextObjectDist(String name) {
    // Build searching filters
    Property[] props = new Property[2];
    props[0] = new Property(".class", "Html.SELECT");
    props[1] = new Property(".text", 
        new RegularExpression("District.*", false));

    // Search for objects
    TestObject[] tobs = find(atDescendant(props), true);
    // Return them
    if(tobs.length == 0)
        return null;
    return (GuiTestObject)tobs[0];
}
```